# Greek letter in Matlab plot

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have created a plot in Matlab and now I would like to add a legend with the following command:

```
legend({'Pos1', 'Pos2', 'Pos3', '\alpha Pos4'}, 'Location', 'northeast', 'Interpreter', 'latex', 'fontsize', 22);
legend('boxoff')
```

The problem is that `\alpha` is not transformed into the greek letter. If I ommit the curly brackets {} then it works but I need them because I only want to label the first four lines.

How can I get the greek letter alpha?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*I want to extend on Daniel's answer and explain some details.*

### What happens without `{}`

When legend entries are *not* specified in a cell array, only the properties `Location` and `Orientation` can be used in the direct call to `legend`. If other properties are present, they are interpreted as legend entries. That means `Interpreter` and `TextSize` and it's values would be legend entries. Adressing Adiel's comment on why it *apparently works* without `{}`: It not really does, it even throws a warning, indirectly because of the above mentioned reasons.

<sup>*Sidenote:* According to the syntax, the legend entries must be provided before the properities. Nevertheless it does work in any order but I do not recommend using this undocumented behaviour.</sup>

### Selecting plots

You mention that you have to use the `{}` to select only the first four lines. This is not true because `legend` selects the first *N* plots by default. The problem was that the properties got interpreted as explained above. To select specific plots, you can use the plot handles to leave out the second plot:

```
legend([ph1,ph3,ph4,ph5], 'Pos1', 'Pos3', 'Pos4', 'Pos5');
```

### Using other properties

To be able to *directly* use other properties in the call to `legend`, you can provide the legend entries as a cell array. This decouples the entries with the name-value-pairs of the properties. For example change the font size:

```
legend({'Pos1', 'Pos2', 'Pos3', 'Pos4'}, 'Fontsize', 22);
```

Another possibility is to use a handle for setting other properties without using a cell array:

```
l = legend('Pos1', 'Pos2', 'Pos3', 'Pos4');
set(l, 'Fontsize', 22);     % using the set-function
l.FontSize = 22;            % object oriented
```

### `latex`-interpreter

If you set `Interpreter` to `latex` then all the contents of the legend entries need to be compilable by latex. That means `\alpha` cannot be used outside a math-environment. To add an inline-math expression in LaTeX you can enclose it with `$`-signs. So `$\alpha$` works as mentioned in Daniel's answer. With the `tex`-interpreter, Matlab uses a subset of the TeX markup and automatically works for the supported special characters, so there would be no need for `$...$` when you don't use the `latex` intrpreter.

---

### Suggestions

- Don't forget the `$`-signs.
- Adress the specific plots in the call to `legend`.
- Use a cell array and set all the properties in the call to `legend` directly.
- With `...` you can split the long line in several ones.

For example like this:

```
legend([ph1,ph3,ph4,ph5], ...
    {'Pos $\alpha$', 'Pos $\beta$', 'Pos $\gamma$', 'Pos  $\delta$'}, ...
    'Location', 'northeast', 'Interpreter', 'latex', 'FontSize', 22);
```

*This is the complete code for the example:*

```
figure; hold on;
ph1 = plot(0,-1,'*'); ph2 = plot(0,-2,'*');
ph3 = plot(0,-3,'*'); ph4 = plot(0,-4,'*');
ph5 = plot(0,-5,'*'); ph6 = plot(0,-6,'*');
legend([ph1,ph3,ph4,ph5], ...
    {'Pos $\alpha$', 'Pos $\beta$', 'Pos $\gamma$', 'Pos  $\delta$'}, ...
    'Location', 'northeast', 'Interpreter', 'latex', 'FontSize', 22);
```

*With this result:*

[image: example]

Answer (score 6):

You forgot the `$`

```
legend({'Pos1', 'Pos2', 'Pos3', '$\alpha$ Pos4'}, 'Location', 'northeast', 'Interpreter', 'latex', 'fontsize', 22);
```

Comment: When the `$` is needed? Why without the `{}` it works?